# What does this DDL Audit example provide

Tags: sql, ddl, audit-logging

Can someone explain this code line by line? I would like to understand the purpose and effect of each line this code has. This code is from Microsoft and doesn't have the best description of what is going on. I plan to use this code and would like to know where the generic names are as well vs the syntactically correct code. THANKS!!

From Microsoft, looked at their documentation but can't find everything

```
enter code here

USE DATABASE;
GO
SELECT *

FROM fn_trace_gettable
(drive, default);
GO

SELECT
  TE.name AS [DLL_EDIT],
  TT.DatabaseName,
  TT.DatabaseID,
  TT.ApplicationName,
  TT.LoginName,
  TT.Duration,
  TT.Duration,
  TT.StartTime,
  TT.EndTime
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(
  CONVERT (VARCHAR(4000),
  (
    SELECT TOP 1
      f.[value]
        FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(NULL) f
          WHERE f.property = 2
          )), DEFAULT
          ) TT
    JOIN
        sys.trace_events TE
    ON TT.EventsClass = TE.trace_events_id
    ORDER BY TT.StartTime desc;



  ))
)
```